# Is it possible to use jquery ajax's auto generated callback with a configured callback name?

Tags: jquery, ajax, callback, jsonp

I'm performing an AJAX JSONP call on a remote server. I want to use the standard jQuery AJAX call without specifying `jsonpCallback`, in order to use jQuery's auto generated callback mechanism. like this:

```js
$.ajax({
    url: thirdPartyUrl,
    dataType: "jsonp",
    cache: false
})
```

The problem is that the 3rd party server doesn't support callback name that contains underscores (only alphanumeric characters are allowed),
and whenever I request the data with the auto generated callback name it fails.

Is there any option to configure the callback **name** without implementing the callback auto generation under the hood?

EDIT: for example:
when I call
http://thirdPartyUrl?ajaxParams&callback=jQuery1111029177630553022027_1431420222555
the server returns error message
but calling
http://thirdPartyUrl?ajaxParams&callback=jQuery1111029177630553022027
(or any other alphanumeric string as a callback) will success

Answer (score 0):

_14314xxxxx for clean cache.try var a callback function with name and callback in url use that name